# Capistrano Production Deploy Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3

I ran the following command to prepare my rails application on a Rackspace cloud and observed the following errors.

```
cap production deploy --trace                                                                   ⏎ ✹
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke deploy:starting (first_time)
** Execute deploy:starting
** Invoke deploy:check (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check
** Invoke git:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper (first_time)
** Execute git:wrapper
 INFO [4761f9bd] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/my_app_name/ on example.com
DEBUG [4761f9bd] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/my_app_name/
cap aborted!
No route to host - connect(2)
/Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:70:in `initialize'
/Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:70:in `open'
/Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:70:in `block in initialize'
/Users/fr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
/Users/fr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:97:in `timeout'
/Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:67:in `initialize'
/Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:200:in `new'
/Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:200:in `start'
/Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:25:in `create_or_reuse_connection'
/Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:173:in `ssh'
/Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:126:in `block in _execute'
/Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:123:in `tap'
/Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:123:in `_execute'
/Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/Users/fr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => git:check => git:wrapper
The deploy has failed with an error: #<Errno::EHOSTUNREACH: No route to host - connect(2)>
** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
** Execute deploy:failed
```

I tried looking up what these errors are pointing, but its quite unclear to me why the message "No route to host" is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

In the log output I see a reference to `example.com`, which probably explains the `No route to host error` you are getting.

Did you specify the domain/ip of the target server in your deploy.rb like this:

```
role :web, %w{your_server.com}
```

as documented here: http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/preparing-your-application/